# File Write - Unauthorized Access Exception

Tags: ios8, xamarin.ios, nsfilemanager, system.io.file

Trying to save a file locally from an app running in the iOS 8 Simulator and I'm continually getting access denied exceptions.

In previous apps I've used the following code to get a valid file path:

```cs
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

or

```cs
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

But I've read that with iOS 8 this has now got to be written as:

```cs
NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,
                                     NSSearchPathDomain.User)[0]
```

So I'm using the following code to generate a file path for a `.txt` file and receiving an access denied exception when trying to save with it:

```cs
public void SaveMyFile(string content)
{
    NSUrl[] urls;
    string filePath;
    //
    urls = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,
                                                NSSearchPathDomain.User);
    filePath = Path.Combine(urls[0].Path, "MyApp", "myFile.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, content);
}
```

So the file path that it gives me and also denies access to is `/Users/Idox/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/92498E38-7D50-4081-8A64-83061DC00A86/data/Containers/Data/Application/C35B3E98-C9E3-4ABA-AA7F-CD8419FA0EA5/Documents/MyApp/myFile.txt`.

I'm wondering if there's some setting that needs to be toggled to give the app write access to this directory or if the directory itself is invalid.

I've also done a call to `Directory.Exists(string path)` to check if the directory is there, which it is.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `Path` property on `urls[0].Path`

```
filePath = Path.Combine(urls[0].Path, "MyApp", "myFile.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was a typo in the question code, oops! I don't think it would've compiled without the `.Path` ;)

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in [Xamarin.iOS 8.4](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_8/xamarin.ios_8.4/), so if you're using a recent version of Xamarin you can use `Environment.GetFolderPath` without problems (which is useful if you want to share code across platforms).

Comment: I'm now using Xamarin.iOS 8.9 with Xamarin Studio on a mac, changing back to using `Environment.GetFolderPath` is still resulting in unauthorized access exceptions. I need to see if still the case when testing on a device instead of the simulator.